# why am i getting time limit exceed

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I was trying to solve this problem in leetcode.
problem: [heap problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/relative-ranks/)

this is my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> findRelativeRanks(vector<int>& score) {
        priority_queue<pair<int,int>,vector<pair<int,int>>>mxheap;
        
        for(int i=0; i<score.size(); i++){
            mxheap.push({score[i],i});
        }
        
        vector<string>ans(score.size());
        int place = 1;
        while(!mxheap.empty()){
            
            switch(place){
                case 1:  
                    ans[mxheap.top().second] = "Gold Medal";
                    mxheap.pop(); 
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ans[mxheap.top().second] = "Silver Medal";
                    mxheap.pop();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ans[mxheap.top().second] = "Bronze Medal";
                    mxheap.pop();
                    break;
                default:
                    ans[mxheap.top().second] = to_string(place);
            }
            place++;
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

I don't know why I am getting the time limit exceeds I also tried removing the pair and using a map but that also didn't work.
I also saw some answers in discuss section those answers were also of (nlogn) time complexity but they worked fine mine is also (nlogn) still its not working can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: you will need to debug this. What have you done in debuggiung?

Comment: These problems usually require you to know or discover a "Trick" that eliminates most of the work. You likely have not discovered the "Trick" yet.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a pop under the default. Endless loop? Since you want to pop in all cases you could move that outside each case into one place after.

Comment: Find which inputs cause you to time out, set it up as a custom input, add some timings and go from there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387586/measuring-execution-time-of-a-function-in-c might be useful if you haven't timed functions before.

Comment: You don't need priority queues for this.  A simple array of indices, sort the indices based on the scores, and then use the sorted indices when accessing the score array to figure out who comes first, second, third, etc.  Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405266/having-trouble-creating-an-array-that-shows-how-the-indices-were-moved-in-anothe/40405691#40405691) explaining how to sort using indices (for your case, use `>` in the sort lambda).

Comment: Just for laughs, I went to the site, implemented my suggestion to you, and got a success on the first try.   I suggest you first sort the indices, look at the sorted index array in the debugger, and from there, you could easily figure out where to place the names in the output vector.

Comment: i am really sorry it wasn't working because i forgot to pop on default case now its working and thanks you all for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not popping off the element in the `default` case.

```
ans[mxheap.top().second] = to_string(place);
mxheap.pop(); // Add this
```

which leads to an infinite while loop since your queue never becomes empty and hence the TLE.

You should be using a debugger to root-cause these problems and add breakpoints in your program to verify the expected program state at those points.