# How to store the original indices of array after sorting the array in ascending ordering

Tags: c++, arrays

Assume that I have a `array_dist`, and I sorted this array in ascending order successfully. But I need also to store the indices of the original array in new array called `index_arr`.
Example: `array [5,4,3,2,1]` has indices `[0,1,2,3,4]`. what I need after sorting the `array [1,2,3,4,5]`. is these indices `[4,3,2,1,0]`

I try the following code which correctly sorted the `array_dist` but not correctly store the indices in `index_arr`

```
int index_arr[4344]{};
for (int i = 0; i < 4344; ++i) {
 index_arr[i] = i;
}
float temp; int x; 
for (int i = 0; i < 4344 ; i++)
{
   for (int j = i + 1; j < 4344; j++)
   {   
       if (array_dist[i] > array_dist[j])
       {
            temp = array_dist[i];
            array_dist[i] = array_dist[j];
            array_dist[j] = temp;
            x = index_arr[i];
            index_arr[i] = index_arr[j];
         index_arr[j] = x;
       }        
    }
}
    
cout << "print out distance colum after ascending sorting : \n";
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 4344; ++i)
 {
     cout << index_arr[i] << " : "
         << array_dist[i] << endl;
 }
```

The correctly working code that I compare my results with:

```
auto sortRuleLambda = [](pair<int, float> const& s1, pair<int, float> const& s2) -> bool
    {
        return s1.second < s2.second;
    };
    sort(array_dist.begin(), array_dist.end(), sortRuleLambda);

     cout << "print out distance colum after ascending sorting : \n";
             for (int i = 0; i < array_X_train.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << array_dist[i].first << ": "
            << array_dist[i].second << endl;
    }
```

Comment: There is no need to sort the original array `array_dist`  at all.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405266/having-trouble-creating-an-array-that-shows-how-the-indices-were-moved-in-anothe/40405691#40405691).  The only array that requires sorting is the index array -- there is a reason why it's called an index array.  Also, why are you using the awful bubble sort, when you could use `std::sort`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am not allowed to use std::sort

Comment: You should mention up front what you are or are not allowed to use, so that answers are not posted and then rejected because the answer uses things we have no idea you can or cannot use.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, what do you mean by "There is no need to sort the original array array_dist at all"

Comment: The whole purpose of the index array is to -- *index* into the original array.   Again, that's why it's called an "index array".  You're just not seeing how to use it properly.

Comment: yes but I want for further steps in my code an array with sorted data and an array with indices of original data

Comment: Look at my answer.  You get both *without* having to sort the original array.  That's the whole point of having an index array.  Also, for more details, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382252/sort-array-by-first-item-in-subarray-c/46382976#46382976)

Comment: Your update missed the whole point.  You are unnecessarily having to sort the data array, when all you need to sort is the index array.  Again, see the answer I posted.

Comment: [Here is what the lambda function should look like](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e63ae1c5eab80d1).  Now unless I'm a magician, how did I get the `array_dist` to print out sorted without actually sorting it?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you very much for your http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e63ae1c5eab80d1, it is work correctly well, but I was wondering what is n1 and n2 in the code ???

Comment: The `n1` and `n2` are the values that the `std::sort` is sending you for comparison.  They come from the `index_array`.

Comment: okay I understand now, I was wondering because I am not required to initialize them

Comment: could you please add your solution as answer so I could marked it as the correct answer for this question. Thank you very much again

Comment: The answer I posted is already there.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, as I told you before that your solution to use sort is working correctly in c++ and gave me correct results for both array's elements and indices. But, earlier today, I tried to use the same code in OpenCL. It gave me error "function 'sort' is invalid in OpenCL" . So, I return back to the same problem. I really need to use the same procedure {bubble sort)  as in my question. But still the indices are not sorted correctly. plz I need your help

Comment: Keep the bubble sort exactly the same that you wrote *except* remove those lines where you are changing `array_dist`, and replace the `if` clause.  That's it.  In other words, the solution is a subset of the code you wrote (a simple cut of 3 lines and a replace of one line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are sorting the original `array_dist` when you shouldn't be sorting this at all.

You should only sort the `index_array` based on the comparison of the `array_dist` values :

```
// Compare values at `array_dist`, using the index array 
if (array_dist[index_array[i]] > array_dist[index_array[j]])
{
   // the indices need to be swapped
   x = index_arr[i];
   index_arr[i] = index_arr[j];
   index_arr[j] = x;
}
```

Once you have this, then to print out the `array_dist` in sorted order:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4344; ++i)
{
   cout << index_arr[i] << " : "
       << array_dist[index_arr[i]] << endl;
}
```

You use the `index_array` as a subscript within the original array.

Comment: I just tried your code it gave me the same results of my code

Comment: Actually I compare my results with other code implemented using pair, begin, end. it gave me slightly difference in indices

Comment: I just update the question with the code that I compare my results with

Comment: The code works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22b0b03a01e8b02d).  Did you make *all* of the changes, including changing the test in the loop, plus print out the array using the index array as a subscript?

Comment: Instead of showing OP how to print out the desired output, you can use the sorted `index_arr` to create a re-arranged `array_dist`. Probably easiest to re-arrange into a new array, and then copy the new array on top of `array_dist`.

Comment: While I agree in general that you should sort an index file   sometimes you get better cache locality sorting the target depending on access needs.

Comment: @jxh I'm assuming he's just trying to debug his code for learning and not trying to write a better `std::sort` which he compares against. Just pointing out that it's not always optimal to sort against an index depending on how the data is used afterwards.

Comment: @doug I understood your overall point. But in the context of this likely being a homework problem, the only locality advantage to sorting the data rather than an index is if the sorting algorithm itself can take advantage of that locality. Quicksort is an example of a sorting algorithm that does so.

Comment: @jxh I was really thinking of other readers that would be, of course, using `std::sort` and needed an index. And I've frequently sorted index and values with the values sorted because my subsequent use of the values in sorted order was extensive and cache locality, especially after chopping values up for multithreading, was most of the work while backtracking via the index was required but infrequent. But I do agree that sorting the index is typically the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
map<int, int> smallest;
int arr[4344];
//do some initialize
for (int i=0;i<4344;i++) 
{
    smallest.insert(pair(arr[i], i));
}
```

Now `smallest` will contain the sorted array by value and contain its corresponding index.
Edit (same but without using map container):

```
class sth //sorry I don't creative with the name
{
public:
    int value, index;
    explicit sth()
    {
        value = 0;
        index = 0;
    }
    sth (const int v, const int i)
    {
        value = v;
        index = i;
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr int n = 10; //make a variable like this will make life easier
    sth* smallest = new sth[n];
    int arr[n] = {1,2,3,-4,12,5,124,-12,22,123};
    //do some initialize
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        smallest[i]=sth(arr[i], i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (smallest[i].value > smallest[j].value)
            {
                sth temp = smallest[i];
                smallest[i] = smallest[j];
                smallest[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the `smallest` array should contain the value and the index of the first array.

Comment: Depending on context: This might be the most clever or crazy answer. +1 for thinking _outside the box_.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, but I am not allowed to use map

Comment: @user16767585 Can you use `vector<pair<int,int>>` ?

Comment: @user16767585 How abt use a struct with two properties: `value`, and `index`?

Comment: okay great. would you please  add your struct as answer so I could try

Comment: @user16767585 okay I fixed it as your demand though the code now has lambda expression. And can you use `std::sort`?

Comment: @user16767585 Oh sorry you can't use sort, just let me fix the code

Comment: Yes so I fixed my code not to use sort, is it what you need?